# Is it possible to make an image always display a minimum height, while always maintaining a minimum 100% width?

Tags: css, image, resolution

I'd like to make an image always be at least 600px height, but still maintaining at least 100% width (while keeping aspect ratio). Over flow on either side is fine. I just want the image to always fill the full width of the screen and always reach at least 600px in height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard (maybe impossible) to achieve what you want. You will have to choose two of the three options (aspect ratio, width, height).

One way to do it would be this, but it can break aspect ratio:

```
img {
    min-height: 600px;
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'm a bit of a newb, but does min-width: 100% make sense?

Comment: Yes, you can use min-width: 100% too.